# How do I sort by single property with a different name in each array item?

Tags: javascript, sorting

Given

```
a = [{"a": 1}, {"b": 0}, {"w", -4}]
```

I want to rearrange this into

```
a = [{"w", -4},{"b": 0}, {"a": 1}]
```

Sort by lowest to greatest

Trying to do this with `a.sort()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting an array of objects by property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values)

Comment: The “duplicate question”, while about sorting, relates to *known* property names. That is not the case here..

Comment: Do you know the names of the variables that you want to sort on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and `Object.values`

```js
a = [{"a": 1}, {"b": 0}, {"w": -4}]
a.sort((a,b)=>Object.values(a)[0]-Object.values(b)[0])
console.log(a)
```

Comment: Could you explain what the sort did?

Comment: it's minus, sort() takes 2 values and then when you want to sort your values in ascending order you do a-b and it will either return -1 or a positive value

Comment: I have added a link if you want to read more about [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: It is a binary numeric subtraction and possibly an error as Object.values() returns an array. I would imagine the correction to be: “return Object.values(a)[0] - ..”, as indexing into the array will return the number.

Comment: Using `Array - Array` would not be the most common approach

Answer (score 0):

Couln't you do it by passing by a map?

Maybe :

```
var map = new Map();

map.set("a", 1);
map.set("b", 0);
map.set("w", -4);
const sortedMapByValue= new Map([...map.entries()].sort((a, b) => a[1] - b[1]));
```

That normally gives you the result you want when iterating on sortedMapByValue

Edit: I haven't seen latest answer, pretty similar, better if you want to keep your array as is it

Comment: Why the first Map when it is stated the given input is an array of objects? And expected results is an array also

Comment: yeah my apologyze, just a suggestion for better readability

Answer (score 0):

You could use sort with a custom comparator like so:

```
  a.sort(( a, b, o=Object.values ) => o(a)[0] - o(b)[0] )
```